# Why not showing Bangla words in Android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to show a list of crops in Bangla/Bengali in the android app. I already have an array of crops in english like  `String[] crops={"paddy","potato","gourd"};`
showing corresponding bangla name in app like if I want to show only "potato",the app will show "আলু" 
I followed the steps shown here: http://www.thedevline.com/2014/08/how-to-build-bangla-language-support.html

But it did not show bangla though app was run. I am working in android studio.
Can anyone please help ?
I have following function in databaseAccess.java file 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00OHI.png)

Comment: what you tried so far ? any exceptions ? error ?

Comment: I tried to run the given code following the steps in the link http://www.thedevline.com/2014/08/how-to-build-bangla-language-support.html. though app runs but dont show the text.It's blank

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I have attached code in question.Can you pls help?

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a custom adapter for listview with your font set

```
    public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);

        //here use your true type font of Bangla like this bangla.ttf is placed inside asset/fonts/ folder of project
        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/bangla.ttf"); 
        textView .setTypeface(face); 
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

use it in your Activity like:

```
 String[] names = new String[] { "আলু", "পেয়াজ", "বাদাম"};
 ListView myListView=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list); //your listview
 myList.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, names));
```

in res/layout: `R.layout.list_item`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: what is the type of myListView? Is it a type of listView in xml file under my activity?@rafsanahmad007

Comment: Thanks a lot! got it :)  @rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 0):

Download library file from`

https://github.com/androidbangladesh/BLS_SAMPLE_APP

and place it to `app\libs`folder.

Now on `build.gradle`file simply add

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/bls-1.0.jar')
}
```

For more information you may visit:
http://www.thedevline.com/2014/08/how-to-build-bangla-language-support.html